# New line (\n) not working in JUNOS on EX3300

Tags: juniper

Hopefully this is a quick fix and someone has seen this. Every document that I have come across tells me that when I am entering a login message, in order to make a new line, I should be using "\n".

`Set system login message "Line1. \nLine2."`

Should produce:

Line1.

Line2.

Instead, it just reads it as text and produces:

Line1. \nLine2.

I'm on an EX3300 using SecureCRT to access the machine. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My deepest apologies to the community. I'm an idiot an hopefully this helps a couple more fools such as myself. Apparently, the output IS working, but when you do a 
`user@switch> show config`

It shows the "\n" elements, but when I logged out and logged back in (this time seeing the active banner message instead of a running configuration), it was correct. Derp.